# jQuery Click to get the class of object and show div with same class

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm trying to do: click on td to show div with same class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td").click(function () {
        var target = $(this).attr("class");
        $("div").show("slow");             //I want this div to have same class as target
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div." + target).show("slow");
```

You have the class in your variable `target`. So use the dot syntax `$('div.class')` for showing the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("div." + target).show("slow");
```

your code becomes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").click(function () {
        var target = $(this).attr("class");
        $("div." + target).show("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").click(function () {
        var target = this.className;
        $("div." + target).show("slow");
    });
});
```